# How to log out in gnome?

Tags: bash

I searched for log out button but  didn't get it. Is there is another option please guide me as I want to log out. Thanks

Comment: Click on the right side of the top bar, drop down the menu, select **Power Off/Log Out**, then choose **Log Out**.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Version please.

Comment: Zorin os........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it through the GUI, you click the button at the far right of the top bar, click power off/logout, and select logout

[image: example:]

If you want to do it through terminal you can type `gnome-sessiong-quit` (This is for if you want to logout through terminal, but still using the GUI)

If you are not in the GUI at all (like in ssh or Terminal view) you just type `exit`.

The first two options will make a message appear stating you will be logged out in 60s, allowing you to select if you want to logout now, cancel or wait.

[image]

Comment: Good! You could also add another possibility: press <kbd>Super</kbd> then search "logout". That is actually a very quick way eliminating the need to take your hands of the keyboard.

Comment: @vanadium You can improve your comment by removing `<kbd>`Super`</kbd>` formatting and using back ticks as a compromise.